# Find all integers $n>1$ such that $n^2|2^n+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

$3$ is clearly an example, but I can't seem to find any other. How do I prove (or disprove) that $3$ is the unique solution?

Comment: [IMO 1990 Problem 3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h60740_2n__1n2_is_an_integer_imo_1990_problem_3).

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime dividing $n$, and use the Little Fermat Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Unanswered queue is already quite long!!!

[Here is the answer] ( [PDF] an 소 1 - Yufei Zhao
yufeizhao.com › exponent_lifting_sol). Go to answer 6.

It would be good if you learn LTE technique from a good resource if you are doing Olympiad problems. Maybe from [here](http://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvYy82LzdjNTI1OGIyMmNjYmZkZGY4MDhhY2ViZTc3MGE1NDRmMzFhMTEzLnBkZg==&rn=TGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm)

Comment: Is that really a link? How does it work?

Comment: Copy *[PDF] ...._lifting_sol* and paste wherever you want @GerryMyerson

Comment: I think http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/exponent_lifting_sol.pdf would be a much better way to give the link.